# How to handle a Docker RUN apt install command that wants to install systemd service

Tags: docker, dockerfile, systemd, apt, ubuntu-server

What is the proper way to go about using an Aptitude package that wants to install a systemd service on Linux within a Docker container?

Here is the output:

```
krzysztof@pop-devx:~/docker2_edgeiq$ docker compose build
[+] Building 3.8s (21/22)                                                                                                                                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 604B                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                                       0.2s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:39b85bbfa7536a5feceb7372a0817649ecb2724562a38360f4d6a7782a409b14                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                 0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 186B                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [ 1/16] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest@sha256:9a0bdde4188b896a372804be2384015e90e3f84906b750c1a53539b585fbbe7f                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/16] WORKDIR /edgeiq                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/16] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/16] RUN apt-get install -y sudo                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/16] RUN sudo apt-get upgrade -y                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/16] RUN sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/16] RUN sudo apt-get install -y zip                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/16] RUN sudo su && echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://apt.fury.io/edgeiq/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/edgeiq.list                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/16] RUN sudo apt-get update                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [10/16] RUN sudo apt-get install edgeiq-edgectl                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [11/16] COPY edgeiq_bootstrap.json .                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [12/16] COPY edgeiq_identifier.json .                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [13/16] RUN pwd                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [14/16] RUN ls -lash                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [15/16] RUN sudo edgectl install -b ./edgeiq_bootstrap.json                                                                                            3.1s
------
 > [15/16] RUN sudo edgectl install -b ./edgeiq_bootstrap.json:
#0 0.272 Installing edge to '/opt/edge/'...
#0 1.051 Downloading edge from https://api.edgeiq.io/api/v1/platform/releases/latest/edge-linux-amd64-latest...
#0 3.058 Issue installing Edge: Issue enabling edge.service: sh: 1: systemctl: not found
#0 3.058 
#0 3.058 exit status 127
#0 3.058 
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sudo edgectl install -b ./edgeiq_bootstrap.json" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
krzysztof@pop-devx:~/docker2_edgeiq$
```

The Dockerfile is the following:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /edgeiq
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN sudo apt-get upgrade -y
#RUN sudo apt-get install -y systemd
RUN sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
RUN sudo apt-get install -y zip
RUN sudo su && echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://apt.fury.io/edgeiq/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/edgeiq.list
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install edgeiq-edgectl
COPY edgeiq_bootstrap.json .
COPY edgeiq_identifier.json .
RUN pwd
RUN ls -lash
RUN sudo edgectl install -b ./edgeiq_bootstrap.json
COPY . .
```

Someone must have though of this because there is a lot of packages in apt that install as a service.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You usually don't install programs as services in a docker image. Usually a container only contains a single process, so there's no need for systemd.

Comment: @HansKilian thank you for that.  You are right.  The application is just a binary that runs an application.  The part that makes it a systemd services is the creation of the text file /etc/systemd/system/edge.service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `edgectl` not to start the service by providing the `--no-start` option:

```
RUN edgectl install -b ./edgeiq_bootstrap.json --no-start
```

You will of course need to figure out how to start the service without using `systemd`. It looks like a systemd unit file is available in `/opt/edge/init/systemd/edge.service`; you should be able to inspect that and extract the appropriate command from the `ExecStart` directive.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you can drop all those `sudo` calls in your Dockerfile. The fact that you're able to install `sudo` in the first place means you're already running as root. You could simplify things down to:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /edgeiq

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates sudo zip
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://apt.fury.io/edgeiq/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/edgeiq.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install edgeiq-edgectl
COPY edgeiq_bootstrap.json .
COPY edgeiq_identifier.json .
RUN pwd; ls -lash
RUN edgectl install -b ./edgeiq_bootstrap.json --no-start
```

Comment: That  ```--no-start``` is an elegant solution.  I don't need to use ```;exit 0``` anymore because it finishes successfully.  I was also able to add ```CMD ["/opt/edge/edge"]``` to get the binary started using ExecStart suggestion.